# Validating fields with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('input:firstName, input:lastName').blur(function() {
    var check = $(this).val();
    if (check == '') {
     $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
    } else {
     $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error');
    }
   });
  });
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>J2EE</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/navbarscroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/applicantFormValidation.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="RegFormModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
   aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <!-- Modal Header -->
     <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> <span class="sr-only ">Close</span>
      </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel ">Apply for job
       Position:</h4>
     </div>

     <!-- Modal Body -->
     <div class="modal-body ">
      <form name="applicationForm" role="form">
       <!--action="ApplicationFormCheck" method="POST"> -->
       <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="firstName" class="col-md-2">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8 ">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName"
          placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstName" />
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="lastName" class="col-md-2">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName"
          placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" />
        </div>
       </div>
       <div style="text-align: center;">
        <button id="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
       </div>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to write a jquery that

1. prevents my modal form from closing,
2. validate the firstName and lastName input fields, if the input fields is/are empty, it will be highlighted in red.

The problem with my Jquery codes is that is doesn't highlight the input fields when it's empty. Please help

My JQuery Codes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input:firstName, input:lastName').blur(function() {
            var check = $(this).val();
            if (check == '') {
                $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
            } else {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What is 'input:firstName", "input:lastName" selectors??

Comment: Can you post demo of your code?

Comment: Demo is not working...

Comment: If it's working I won't have posted and ask?

Comment: Posted an answer, check if it's working. Your demo is not rendering itself, thats what I wanted to convey

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('input:firstName, input:lastName').blur(function() {
        var check = $(this).val();
        if (check == '') {
            $(this).parent().addClass('input-validation-error');
        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('input-validation-error');
        }
    });
  });
});
```

And give properties to your input validation error class using css

```
  .input-validation-error
   { 
     border: 1px solid #ff0000;
     background-color: #ffeeee;
   }
```

Comment: if I want to use bootstrap "has-error" class instead?

Comment: has error class only sets border-color You have to apply border-style by your own

Answer (score -1):

I think your selectors `:firstName` and `:lastName` are wrong. it should be `id` selector.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input#firstName, input#lastName').blur(function() {
            var check = $(this).val();
            if (check == '') {
                $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
            } else {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```